# Android Layout ImageView Not Displayed When TextView Has Long Text

Tags: android, android-layout

I am trying to create a layout that has 3 imageviews going down vertically
next to each imageview I want a Text view as a title, and a text view as a description

https://i.stack.imgur.com/PfODh.png

This is what I am trying so far: but when the title or decription text is long, it removes the imageview from the display (as shown in photo above)
I want the imageview to always show on the left, and the title/description to just show on the right hand side of the imageview.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingBottom="0dip"
            android:paddingLeft="10dip"
            android:paddingRight="10dip"
            android:paddingTop="0dip" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/Iv1"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:layout_weight=".1"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv11"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Title goes here..."
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv12"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight=".2"
                    android:text="Description goes here..."
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                    android:textStyle="" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingBottom="0dip"
            android:paddingLeft="10dip"
            android:paddingRight="10dip"
            android:paddingTop="0dip" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/iv2"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:layout_weight=".1"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv21"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Title goes here..."
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv22"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight=".2"
                    android:text="Description goes here..."
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                    android:textStyle="" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingBottom="0dip"
            android:paddingLeft="10dip"
            android:paddingRight="10dip"
            android:paddingTop="0dip" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/iv3"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:layout_weight=".1"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv31"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Title goes here..."
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv32"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight=".2"
                    android:text="Description goes here..."
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                    android:textStyle="" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </TableRow>


        <Button
            android:id="@+id/BT1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:drawablePadding="10dip"
            android:drawableRight="@drawable/ic_launcher"
            android:text="CLOSE" />
    </LinearLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try do it this way:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_in_call_touch_hold" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView1"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="title" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="long long text long long text long long text long long text long long text long long text long long text long long text long long text " />
        </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_in_call_touch_hold" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView1"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="title" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="long long text long long text long long text long long text long long text long long text long long text long long text long long text " />
        </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_in_call_touch_hold" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView1"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="title" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="long long text long long text long long text long long text long long text long long text long long text long long text long long text " />
        </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

But using ListView will be the best solution.

Comment: Thanks. I ended up using relative layout as I could use the align properties to get the display as I wanted.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting the `imageView` and the `LinearLayout` (containing the two `TextView`s) inside a `linearLayout`. Then give the linear layout a `weightSum` of maybe 100. Then give the `imageView` a `layout_weight` of 70, and the `linearLayout` a `layout_weight` of 30.